# Xcode SpriteKit SKNode Class not executing code on Main Scene

Tags: ios, xcode

The Main scene calls the SKNode object and adds the sprite to the main scene, etc.  When the sprite is finished / destroyed I want to remove the sprite from the main scene and update the score.  However when I try to execute the call form the SKNode it doesn't seem to run but I get no errors either.

Below is the code I have right now.  It's not the complete code just the code that is part of the issue / non issue :)

```
EnemyNode.h

#import "MyScene.h"

@class MyScene;

@interface EnemyNode : SKNode
@property (nonatomic, assign) MyScene *_scene;

EnemyNode.m

-(void)enemyEscaped
{
    NSLog(@"Enemy Escaped");

    [_scene.enemyArray removeObject:_enemy];
    [_scene enemyAttackedBase];

    [_enemy removeAllChildren];
    [_enemy removeAllActions];
    [_enemy removeFromParent];

    [self removeFromParent];
}

MyScene.h
#import "EnemyNode.h"

@class EnemyNode;

@interface MyScene : SKScene

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger myMoney;
@property (nonatomic) EnemyNode *_enemy;

- (void)enemyWasDestroyed:(NSUInteger)money;

MyScene.m
- (void)enemyWasDestroyed:(NSUInteger)money
{
    NSLog(@"money, money, money %lu", (unsigned long)money);

    self.myMoney += money;

    SKLabelNode *moneyLabel = (SKLabelNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"moneyHUD"];
    moneyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Money: %lu",(unsigned long)self.myMoney];
}
```

when I call 
[_scene.enemyArray removeObject:_enemy];
[_scene enemyAttackedBase];

Nothing happens on the main scene (i.e. the money label does not update).

Any ideas?

Am I completely wrong in how I am doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake.  I wasn't defining what _scene was during the init process.

Changed the init from;

```
+(id)initNodewithSpriteTexture:(SKTexture *)texture forSpriteNode:(SKSpriteNode *)spriteNode atPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
return [[self alloc] initScene:scene withSpriteTexture:texture forSpriteNode:spriteNode atPosition:position];
}
```

to;

```
+(id)initNodeForGame:(MyScene*)scene withSpriteTexture:(SKTexture *)texture forSpriteNode:(SKSpriteNode *)spriteNode atPosition:(CGPoint)position
{

    return [[self alloc] initScene:scene withSpriteTexture:texture forSpriteNode:spriteNode atPosition:position];
}

-(id)initScene:(MyScene*)scene withSpriteTexture:(SKTexture*)texture forSpriteNode:(SKSpriteNode*)spriteNode atPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _scene = scene;
}
```

Now everything works like it should.